# Able to ping to an IP, but not able to browse on that IP from Azure vm

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have created a VM in azure..
when i try to browse from the Internet explorer in vm to an ip it is not working..
eg ->   https://10.x.x.x/sladata

But when i try o ping from the commandd prompt in the vm, it is working.

eg -> ping 10.x.x.x

Could anyone helps to solve this..

Regards
akhil

Comment: If ping works as expected but browser access does not, it may be a hint that the ports for http and https are not open or are not being forwarded.

You should check the network settings of your azure VM and see if ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) have been enabled.

See the docu for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal

Answer (score 1):

> The standard ping command does not use TCP or UDP. It uses ICMP. To be
>   more precise ICMP type 8 (echo message) and type 0 (echo reply
>   message) are used. ICMP has no ports!
>
> See RFC792 for further details.

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/37897

The reason you cannot see the page is probably because port 443 (default for SSL) is not open in the NSG.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal